# do while loop not working properly

Tags: c++

I want the user to input a date that falls before or equal to May 30,2016 and not below than January 1,2016. If the input is not valid then it should go back and ask question again to the user. The problem is that `do...while` loop is not looping, it stops after the input is invalid. Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int month,day,year;
    char symbol;

    do{
        cout<<"Enter date: ";
        cin>>month>>symbol>>day>>symbol>>year;

        if(symbol=='/'&&month<=05&&day<=31&&year==2016){
            cout<<month<<symbol<<day<<symbol<<year;

            if(month==01){          // this code is for month of January
                if(day==3||day==10||day==17||day==24||day==31){
                    cout<<" is Sunday.";
                }
                else if(day==4||day==11||day==18||day==25){
                    cout<<" is Monday.";
                }
                else if(day==5||day==12||day==19||day==26){
                    cout<<" is Tuesday.";
                }
                else if(day==6||day==13||day==20||day==27){
                    cout<<" is Wednesday.";
                }
                else if(day==7||day==14||day==21||day==28){
                    cout<<" is Thursday.";
                }
                else if(day==1||day==8||day==15||day==22||day==29){
                    cout<<" is Friday.";
                }
                else if(day==2||day==9||day==16||day==23||day==30){
                    cout<<" is Saturday.";
                }

            }
            else if(month==02){     //this code is for month of February
                if(day==7||day==14||day==21||day==28){
                    cout<<" is Sunday.";
                }
                else if(day==1||day==8||day==15||day==22||day==29){
                    cout<<" is Monday.";
                }
                else if(day==2||day==9||day==16||day==23){
                    cout<<" is Tuesday.";
                }
                else if(day==3||day==10||day==17||day==24){
                    cout<<" is Wednesday.";
                }
                else if(day==4||day==11||day==18||day==25){
                    cout<<" is Thursday.";
                }
                else if(day==5||day==12||day==19||day==26){
                    cout<<" is Friday.";
                }
                else if(day==6||day==13||day==20||day==27){
                    cout<<" is Saturday.";
                }   
            }
            else if(month==03){         //this code is for month of March

                if(day==6||day==13||day==20||day==27){
                    cout<<" is Sunday.";
                }
                else if(day==7||day==14||day==21||day==28){
                    cout<<" is Monday.";
                }
                else if(day==1||day==18||day==15||day==22||day==29){
                    cout<<" is Tuesday.";
                }
                else if(day==2||day==9||day==16||day==23||day==30){
                    cout<<" is Wednesday.";
                }
                else if(day==3||day==10||day==17||day==24||day==31){
                    cout<<" is Thursday.";
                }
                else if(day==4||day==11||day==18||day==25){
                    cout<<" is Friday.";
                }
                else if(day==5||day==12||day==19||day==26){
                    cout<<" is Saturday.";
                }
            }
            else if(month==04){     //this code is for month of April

                if(day==3||day==10||day==17||day==24){
                    cout<<" is Sunday.";
                }
                else if(day==4||day==11||day==18||day==25){
                    cout<<" is Monday.";
                }
                else if(day==5||day==12||day==19||day==26){
                    cout<<" is Tuesday.";
                }
                else if(day==6||day==13||day==20||day==27){
                    cout<<" is Wednesday.";
                }
                else if(day==7||day==14||day==21||day==28){
                    cout<<" is Thursday.";
                }
                else if(day==1||day==8||day==15||day==22||day==29){
                    cout<<" is Friday.";
                }
                else if(day==2||day==9||day==16||day==23||day==30){
                    cout<<" is Saturday.";
                }
            }   
            else if(month==05){     //this code is for month of May

                if(day==1||day==8||day==15|day==22||day==29){
                    cout<<" is Sunday.";
                }
                else if(day==2||day==9||day==16||day==23||day==30){
                    cout<<" is Monday.";
                }
                else if(day==3||day==10||day==17||day==24||day==31){
                    cout<<" is Tuesday.";
                }
                else if(day==4||day==11||day==18||day==25){
                    cout<<" is Wednesday.";
                }
                else if(day==5||day==12||day==19||day==26){
                    cout<<" is Thursday.";
                }
                else if(day==6||day==13||day==20||day==27){
                    cout<<" is Friday.";
                }
                else if(day==7||day==14||day==21||day==28){
                    cout<<" is Saturday.";
                }
            }
            break;  
        }
        else{
            cout<<"You have entered an invalid input.\n"<<endl;
        }
    }while(symbol!='/'&&!(month<=05)&&!(day<=31)&&year!=2016);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know there are formulas for the day of the week, you don't have to write a zillion if statements listing all the dates. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week

Comment: And something like `if(day==3||day==10||day==17||day==24||day==31)` can be simplified to `if (day % 7 == 3)`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read that from wikipedia.

Comment: But how can I make do...while loop to work?

Comment: See the answer that was posted. The problem was that your `while` condition was wrong.

Comment: @Barmar - I have changed the code in while loop from && to || . It is while(symbol!='/' || !(month<=05) || !(day<=31) || year!=2016);

Comment: That's very nice to know.

Comment: It's just what @4386427 said below. hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(symbol!='/'&&!(month<=05)&&!(day<=31)&&year!=2016);
```

must be

```
while(symbol!='/' || !(month<=05) || !(day<=31) || year!=2016);
```

or as suggested by @Barmar

```
while(symbol!='/' || (month>05) || (day>31) || year!=2016);
```

Your original expression requires all 4 to be true due to the `&&`. The expression using `||` requires just one of them to be true.

Also notice that you don't need that check as you already have an `if` inside.

So you could just do:

```
while (true) {
    cout<<"Enter date: ";

    cin>>month>>symbol>>day>>symbol>>year;

    // clear cin
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(10000,'\n');  // Or better:
                             // std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()
                             // instead of just 10000 

    if(symbol=='/' && month<=05 && day<=31 && year==2016){
        // code for handling valid date here

        // This will end the while loop
        break;  
    }
    else{
        cout<<"You have entered an invalid input.\n"<<endl;
    }
};
```

Unrelated: Also notice this line

```
cin>>month>>symbol>>day>>symbol>>year;
            ^^           ^^
```

Here you read into `symbol` twice, i.e. the second value will just overwrite the first. Instead you would need

```
cin >> month >> symbol1 >> day >> symbol2 >> year;
                      ^                 ^
```

and of cause change the rest of the code accordingly.

> Update

The code can be tested here https://ideone.com/KvCy1e

With the input

```
dem/dem/dem
1/1/2016
```

the output is

```
Enter date: You have entered an invalid input.

Enter date: 1/1/2016 is Friday.
```

> Update 2

As noticed by @Barmar in a comment, you should initialize your variables to some invalid date before the loop.

```
int month = 13;
int day = 32;
int year = 0;
char symbol = 'x';
```

And btw: Since you use `ints` you should check for negative values.

Comment: `!(month <= 5)` can be simplified to `month > 5`. Or you could combine all the conditions using de Morgan's Law, that will probably make it clearer.

Comment: The loop is now working but it doesn't stop to output "Enter date: You have entered an invalid input."... and I'ts look like a matrix. hehe. Why is this?

Comment: @Dem - That must be because the values entered isn't valid. For debug, add a `cout` of the values just after the `cin`

Comment: @Bamar - true, it can be written differently - I wanted to keep the style of OP to make the difference clear

Comment: @Dem - what did you enter? Be very precise about it... If I input `1/1/2016` I get `Enter date: 1/1/2016 is Friday.`

Comment: I input Dem/Dem/Dem so that it will loop and go back and ask the question again because of the invalid input, but the matrix is what I see.

Comment: @Dem What do you expect it to set `month` to when you enter `Dem` instead of a number? Your code just checks the amounts, you're never testing whether the input was formatted correctly as numbers.

Comment: @Barmar - That's why I used else statement so that if it doesn't fit on any if statements then it will go back and ask question again-but it's not what's happening.

Comment: @4386427 - Thanks, but still it makes the matrix. I added of what you just changed.

Comment: @4386427 - It now works fine, but my professor said that we should not use other topics that we did not have discuss yet like what you have added in my code. But thank you (very much) by the way. :D

Comment: @Dem It only goes back to ask the question if the condition in the `while()` is true. But if the input isn't numbers, you have uninitialized values in all the variables.

Comment: @Barmar - So do...while loop doesn't work if (!(true statement))?

Comment: The problem is that the value of the condition is unpredictable if the variables are not initialized.